# regular expression for four names

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I want to make a validation on the name, to force the user to input his name in four sections (four names). How to do that on the client side, using asp.net validation?

```
<td style="text-align: right;" class="style1">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_addName" runat="server" Width="220px" ValidationGroup="add"></asp:TextBox>
    <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txt_addName_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" 
        runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txt_addName"
        WatermarkText="أدخل اسم المحاضر رباعيا" WatermarkCssClass="watermark">
    </cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
    &nbsp;
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" 
         ControlToValidate="txt_addName" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="!"     
         ValidationGroup="add"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
        ValidationExpression="^(?:\p{L}+\s+){3}\p{L}+$" ControlToValidate="txt_addName"
        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="add">يجب أن يكون اسم المحاضر رباعيا 
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 550px;">
     <asp:Button ID="btn_addNewLecterer" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Garamond"
          Font-Size="Medium" Text="أضف محاضر جديد" OnClick="btn_addNewLecterer_Click" ValidationGroup="add" />
</td>
```

Comment: What is the delimiter between sections ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
^(?:\p{L}+\s+){3,}\p{L}+\s*$
```

Explanation:

```
^      // start at the beginning of the string
(?:    // start a non-capturing group
\p{L}  // match any unicode letter...
+      // ...at least one of them...
\s+    // ...followed by at least one white-space character
)      // end the non-capturing group
{3,}   // repeat the group at least three times
\p{L}+ // finish with at least one unicode character...
\s*    // ...that can optionally be followed by white-space...
 $     // ...and then the string should end
```

If you want to limit the expression to require *exactly* four sections (I interpreted the question as requiring *at least* four), you change it to:

```
^(?:\p{L}+\s+){3}\p{L}+$
```

Comment: thanks ,but it is a server side, i want to check in the client side , through the asp.net validation.

Comment: @just_name: edited the answer to use regex that should be possible to use client-side as well.

Comment: i don't know what is the problem , it always show the message ,"less than four" although i entered four parts.

Comment: @just_name: can you give an example of input that you are testing with?

Comment: @just_name: that is odd. The following code returns `true`: `Regex.IsMatch("أحمد محمد ابراهيم علي", @"^(?:\p{L}+\s+){3}\p{L}+$")`.

Comment: @just_name: something went wrong in copy/paste there. The code I tested is this: `Regex.IsMatch("أحمد محمد ابراهيم علي", @"^(?:\p{L}+\s+){3}\p{L}+$")`

Comment: what may be the reason for this problem, i make a validation group and still the same problem.

Comment: @just_name: I think that the problem is not with the regular expression but rather the setup of validation, where I don't have much knowledge unfortunately.

Comment: when i try for example 

`\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*` for email address and entered an email , to make sure the setup validation ,every thing is okay.but when i try this expression some thing goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You would want something like this:

```
^\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+$
```

You want to use the `+` instead of the `*` because you do want at least one of each.

Use `\w` because you want to catch all word characters - not just letters `a-z`

You could also use literal spaces instead of the `\s` class, as long as you haven't explicitly specified that you want your pattern to ignore white space, so:

```
^\w+ \w+ \w+ \w+$
```

The `\s` would allow a tab to count as well as the space.

And as Frederik noted, as long as you have the validation control's client-side validation enabled, such a simple regex will work client-side as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try regular expression creation programs like Regex Buddy to create your own rules.
Here is the simple one that will allow only four name parts (all small letters) separated by spaces

```
^[a-z]*\s[a-z]*\s[a-z]*\s[a-z]*$
```

You may refine and use this as a base.

Comment: I'd recommend just using 'word characters' as the classes for each group representing each name, to permit names that might have characters other than the 26 represented by `a-z`. For example, check out the name of the person who edited this question...

Comment: @Andrew Barber, This is very crude and the first steps. I have not that much time to refine and test it.

Comment: `+` quantifier is more appropriate than `*`

Comment: i wanna letters other than English letters , how to make it more general.please

Comment: @M42 you are right; I missed that. The given expression actually won't work at all if someone just typed multiple spaces, since it doesn't require any characters at all.